# batch command to copy a file when modified date is same as current date

Tags: windows, time, batch-file, cmd

Batch command will check one file's modified date. if the modified date is equal to the current date then it will copy the file to different location by creatibng a folder of current date.
i have used the code below :

```
@echo off
set currentDate=%date%
SET filename="C:\Documents and Settings\302444\Desktop\inventory.txt"
FOR %%X IN (%filename%) DO SET filedatetime=%%~tX
pause

if %filedatetime:~0, 10% == %currentDate% 
pause
(ROBOCOPY C:\Documents and Settings\302444\Desktop   C:\Documents and Settings\302444\Desktop\IMP\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% inventory.txt
pause
)

if %filedatetime:~0, 10% LSS %currentDate%
(echo file not updated
 pause
)
```

But the if statement is not working here. please advice me on the same

Comment: 07/27/2013 is the date format .. mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: if i use   set currentDate=%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4% then also it is not working . please help me

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer .

1. "" will not be there  and the braces will start from the same line of if like below :

if %filedatetime:~0, 10% == %currentDate%  (ROBOCOPY C:\Documents and Settings\302444\Desktop   C:\Documents and Settings\302444\Desktop\IMP\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% inventory.txt

)

1. and also the current date will set as

currentdate=%date:~-10%.

It is working. thanks for your time .